# US Government Spending

Tags: usa, government, spending

Where can I find a summary of historical spending of the US federal government?

I am not interested in budgets, I am interested in knowing what was actually spent.

Answer (score 2):

You might consider getting in touch with the [Data Lab](https://datalab.usaspending.gov/) at the Treasury Department, they're actively working on the USA Spending site and also the gov spending data. They might have a good sense of where you can look and would likely be interested in what you are hoping to do with the data.

I know that at least at one point they had data dating back to at least 2000 on their site, because the company I work for, Enigma, has made use of it. (You can see some of that on our public data site, [Enigma Public](https://public.enigma.com/browse/collection/u-s-government-spending-contracts/1a932abc-8398-47ff-ad33-d1eb9a8958cc).)

*Disclosure: As stated above, I work for [Enigma](http://enigma.com).*

Comment: Upvote, bookmarked Enigma.  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of data the government releases in many different formats - it feels like a maze at times.  I found a few interesting links for you which I left below.

Some of them get specific, some of them... "miscellaneous."  Lots of different reports for different things.

There appears to be a lot to wade through; except for the very last suggestion / link I found (which admittedly isn't very historical).

Hope this helps:

https://www.federalreserve.gov/datadownload/Choose.aspx?rel=Z1

Here's a news feed for it:
https://www.federalreserve.gov/feeds/z1.html#2090

Or this with a bit of poking around:
https://www.usaspending.gov

I poked around and found this: https://www.usaspending.gov/#/download_center/custom_account_data

Selected Federal Account radio button, all agencies, account breakdown by program activity and class, and got a pretty thorough csv breakdown (45,000 rows).  Apparently it doesn't go back prior 2017 though.

Pretty interesting actually.